# Give access to Roles and Subordinates for already exsisting cases

Tags: apex, roles, sharing-rule

I have Case and its Child **Transaction-1 and Transaction-2**. **Transaction-1 and Transaction-2** has `lookup` relationship to `Case`. `Case`, `Transaction-1` and `Transaction-2` OWD is Private.

In Prod box, I have almost 100 cases. I have created some sharing Rules on Case object, the same sharing rules replicated on Transaction-1 and Transaction-2 object so sharing between Parent and child is consistent.

Sharing Rules giving Readonly access to Roles and Subordiantes, so this will work for newly created Case.

Also when Case is getting submitted successfully, Queue becomes the Owner of the Case. In this Queues, public Groups are present and all users inside that group getting access. Now, Roles and Subordinates concept added which will grant access to newly present cases. What about the older 100 cases which are present in Prod and yet to closed ?

I know CaseShare, Transaction_1_Share and Transaction_2_Share same record will be shared with Public Group, Queue etc. so How can I give access to old 100 cases for the Roles and Subordinates?

Please suggest ways.

Answer (score 2):

For existing cases, there is a button called `Recalculate` where you have defined the sharing rules and clicking on the button, Salesforce will perform recalculation and update the visibility.

[image: recalculate]

Comment: Are you sure ? This will happened automatically ?

Comment: are you facing any issues?